# Need a SW Engineer's input: CS or SWEN?

Tags: software-industry

I am attending Auburn University and need to decide between majoring in Computer Science and Software Engineering.

SWEN requires an additional 16 credit hours, and I want to know from you, the software engineer, if those classes (or the SWEN distinction) sound like they'd make me more employable.

Here are the descriptions of the four most important classes that distinguish the SWEN curriculum from the CS curriculum:

**Computer Architecture**
- Comparison of computer architectures, emphasizing the relationships between system software and hardware. Includes processor control and data path organization, memory subsystem design, instruction set design, processor simulation, and quantitative analysis of computer performance.

**Senior Design Project** - Development of requirement definitions, architectural design specification, detailed design specification, testing plan and documentation for the software and/or hardware components of a comprehensive project.

**Software Process**
- Process models of the software lifecycle as well as methods and tools for software development.

**Software Quality Assurance**
- Processes, methods, and tools associated with the production of robust, high-quality software.

Here [CS vs. SWEN](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lcg3cOr74hv3rmj6xUxMtdlFB1NzAdVvgX1CbXS6LSE/edit?usp=sharing) is a spreadsheet detailing both options. It contains links to syllabi of SWEN-only classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWEN has a bit more subject matter content, but it's not a decisive factor if I were looking for a software engineer.

The first thing I'd look for from you is evidence that you can write well architected, well written code. If you, as a CS major, hand in well architected, well written code and the SWEN you are competing with doesn't, you get the nod. You may end up having to code in a less than optimal way as a result of having to support legacy code, but I'd like to see an awareness of best practices from you.

You know what, I'd hire an English major if they could show me that they can deliver well architected, well written code and if the job does not require a strong competence with data algorithms and theoretical computer science.

At the end of the day, your credentials - work experience and skills set - don't architect and write code, you do. Let's see what you can do.

Comment: I agree with your answer. The problem is it appears the programs are identical outside of those additional engineering based courses. In other words both majors will be taking the same courses outside of those 16 additional credits that are required.  At the end of the day you recieve a dgree which can help make you stand out from everyone else.

Comment: @Ramhound I am pretty sure that there are PhDs in CS who couldn't write well architected, well written code if their lives depended on it. The 16 credits are fine if you care that much about credentials. I don't. You could be the top  graduate from Harvard Med School and go to pieces in a hospital emergency room.

Comment: I hold a great deal of respect for anyone who starts and receives a degree.  But its only respect because they started something then finished it.  I was just pointing out in this particular case, its unlikely either degree will teach him different software skills, a matter if he wants to learn engineerig skills.

Comment: From a hiring perspective where we would not immediately see the transcript, I would consider these two roughly equal. Someplaces one is harder than the other and in other places, the other is the harder one.

Answer (score 2):

While I would say yes they sound like they would make you more employable, I'm not sure if the difference would be statistically significant or not,e.g. they may make you .0000000000000000002% more employable which while greater than zero isn't that meaningful to my mind. I hold a Computer Science degree, work currently as a Senior Software Developer and didn't pursue a Software Engineering option when I was in university 20 years ago.

Consider the question of whether you'd want to learn this material in a classroom pursuing your degree or on your own in an independent form as if you do plan on being a software developer then some of that material you'll learn one way or another. Which works best for you isn't something I can answer for you though.

Comment: I have a degree in Mathematics and am a Software Developer.